# File Upload Odoo 10 Custom Addons

Tags: python, odoo-10

Hi there i'm using custom wizard on my custom module to upload file 
heres my code

```
class BillWizardUpload(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "uploadbillpostfinance.wizard"
    _description = "For XML Postfinance"

    data = fields.Binary(string="Upload File")
    file_name = fields.Char(string="File Name")

    @api.multi
    def import_file(self):

        # your treatment
        return {}
```

my XML file

```
<record id="upload_xml_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Upload XML PostFinance</field>
    <field name="model">uploadbillpostfinance.wizard</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <field name="data" filename="file_name" />
                <field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
            </group>

            <footer>
                <button name="import_file" string="Import" type="object"  class="oe_highlight" />
                or
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

I'm a little bit confused what todo inside function import file, the file i'm going to upload is XML and want to directly process the xml without saving it to Database or file any idea or example how to do it?

Regard

Danial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using normal get/post request like this

```
 @api.multi
def import_file(self,context=None):
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(self.data)
    xml_filelike = io.BytesIO(decoded_data)
    do what you want with file here
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add functions. Just a binary field is required in Odoo for file upload.